# Get Azure Resources details

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to get details of any resource within a resource group.

For eg. I have a publicIP Address resource which has a DNS name and a Public IP address, now I want to get the DNS name and the IP address through powershell.

I can get them through the portal but I want those values to be added in a script so I want to get them through powershell.

I tried few commands but didn't help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the resourceId you can use:

```
(Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/{resourceName}).Properties.dnsSettings
```

Change the provider namespace, etc and that will work for any resource.